# Header text color of a TitleWindow

Tags: css, apache-flex

How do I set the color of the text in the header of the `TitleWindow`? I've changed the color of the header itself by using 'header-colors', but I haven't figured out how to change the color of the text in the header.

edit: some code:

My css file:

```
.popupWindow
{
    border-color: #000000;
    border-alpha: 1;
    header-colors: #000000, #000000; /* This colors the header black, but the text in the header should be white */
}
```

My TitleWindow:

```
<mx:TitleWindow
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    styleName="popupWindow"
    title="This text should be white!"
>
    <!-- Some stuff to fill the TitleWindow -->
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, can we see some source code to help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`titleStyleName`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/Panel.html#style:titleStyleName) in addition to the `styleName`:

```
.popupWindow
{
  border-color: #000000;
  header-colors: #00FF00, #0000FF; 
}
.popupWindowTitle
{
  color:#FF0000;
  fontStyle:italic;
}
<mx:TitleWindow
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    styleName="popupWindow"
    titleStyleName="popupWindowTitle"
    title="This text will be red in a blue-green gradient - and italic!">

    <!-- Some stuff to fill the TitleWindow -->

</mx:TitleWindow>
```